# Please explain strange HTML table rowspan behaviour

Tags: html, html-table

Consider the following HTML table definition.

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan='2'>A</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td rowspan='2'>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan='2'>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I expect the table to look like:

```
+---+---+---+
| A | 2 | B |
|   +---+   |
|   | C |   |
+---+   +---+
| 1 |   | 3 |
+---+---+---+
```

But in Firefox, IE8, and Chrome, the table is rendered like:

```
+---+---+---+
| A | 2 | B |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | C | 3 |
+---+---+---+
```

If I add another column to the table, like so:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>a</td>
   <td rowspan='2'>A</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td rowspan='2'>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>b</td>
   <td rowspan='2'>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>c</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

...I get the following, which is more like what I want.

```
+---+---+---+---+
| a | A | 2 | B |
+---+   +---+   |
| b |   | C |   |
+---+---+   +---+
| c | 1 |   | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Questions:

1. Are the browsers behaving correctly?  If so, why does the table collapse non-intuitively in the case of the first HTML segment given above?
2. Is there any valid HTML/css that will force the table to display as I intend it to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this actually works...
Your cell height isn't fixed, so it seems as if it doesn't work. But if you try it like this:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td height="50px" rowspan="2">A</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You'll see that the table behaves as you want:

[image: Table Result with border]
<sub>(source: [myimg.de](http://img8.myimg.de/Bildschirmfoto148e98_thumb.jpg))</sub>

So if you want your table to look like you explained, I think all you need to do is define the cell height in css or like i described above.

Comment: I have confirmed that your solution works (with css also), but it requires that the height styling rule be applied to a particular td element.  I'm still hoping for a solution that is more easily applicable to the general case.  And I'm still curious as to why the browsers behave in this way.

Comment: The behavior is not strange at all. Its the same with the width of a cell. If you don't define the width, it will align to the content.  Thats the same with the height and rowspan="2". If you put more content in cell A, B or C you won't need the height attribute.

Why do you think its hard applicable to define a css class which contains the rowspan definition and the height? so you would use `<td class="rowsp">`.

Comment: I confirmed that the same behaviour occurs with width as with height by creating a transposed table (rows become columns) and observing the rendering.  The result was as you would predict.  So I am convinced that this is just the way HTML tables work.

Comment: I thought this behaviour was strange because I thought a browser should understand that the table in the question was shorthand for a table with three rows: {A, 2, B}, {A, C, B}, and {1, C, 3}.  By that interpretation, the rendering is incorrect because the rendered row {1, C, 3} does not exist in the HTML table definition.  I see now that HTML tables just do not work that way.

Comment: This question was prompted by an unexpected result I saw while testing a cell-merging method designed to work on a data set defining an arbitrary table.  By my comment that your solution is not easily applicable to the general case, I meant that the problem of automatically setting the height for each td element spanning multiple rows, depending on the number of rows spanned, required a little more work than I had hoped for.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help! I had the same problem: "rowspan not working". I tried the height property trick but it didn't help. After search for hours another trick on Internet, I noticed my `tr` tags were not closed properly: `<tr>...<tr>` instead of `<tr>...</tr>`, and my rowspan was rendering like expected.